# JS RegExp not capture the match

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a regular expression like this :

```
/(?:<script\s+[^>]*?src="([^"]+)"[^>]*><\/script>)|(?:<link\s+[^>]*?href="([^"]+)"[^>]*>)/g
```

I want to replace the "src" in `<script>` tag, or "href" in `<link />` tag with javascript with this regexp.

the code like this :

```
html.replace( /(?:<script\s+[^>]*?src="([^"]+)"[^>]*><\/script>)|(?:<link\s+[^>]*?href="([^"]+)"[^>]*>)/g, function( m, n ) {
    return m.replace( n, 'other url' );
}
```

It is working fine with `<script>` tag but not link tag. coz the regexp still set the first match in ([^"]+) in to the arguments, so that the "n" param is undefined as it is not match `<script>` tag. if the regexp match a `<link>` tag, the code must be modified to :

```
html.replace( /(?:<script\s+[^>]*?src="([^"]+)"[^>]*><\/script>)|(?:<link\s+[^>]*?href="([^"]+)"[^>]*>)/g, function( m, n ) {
    return m.replace( arguments[ 2 ], 'other url' );
}
```

Is there any way to make the regexp not capture the first match if it does not match a `<script>` tag?

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like what you want is:

```
html.replace(/(<script\s[^>]*?src="|<link\s[^>]*?href=")[^"]+"/g, function ($0, $1) {
    return $1 + 'other url' + '"';
});
```

(with the usual caveats that ["You can't parse [X]HTML with regex"](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/978917)).

---

**Edited to add:** The "minimal fix" would be to write your replacement-function like this:

```
function ($0, $1, $2) {
    return m.replace($1 || $2, 'other url');
}
```

where `||` is the Boolean OR operator: `$1 || $2` means "if `$1` is [truthy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Truthy), then `$1`; otherwise, `$2`". A non-empty string is truthy, whereas `undefined` is falsy, so `$1 || $2` will evaluate to whichever of your capture-groups matched something.

(Note: if your capture-groups were able to match the empty string, you'd have to write something a bit more complicated, since you wouldn't want to end up with `$2` if `$1` is `''` and `$2` is `undefined`. But in your example that doesn't apply.)

Comment: thanks. I know how to solve this problem. In fact i want to know something about regexp

Comment: @LCB: OK. I've edited my answer to provide a "minimal fix" for you. Though it doesn't actually have to do with the regex at all!

Answer (score 0):

@ruakh is correct, you shouldn't be using regex to parse html, try this instead

```
var div = document.createElement('div');
div.innerHTML = html;

var scriptTags = div.getElementsByTagName('script');
for (var i = 0; i < scriptTags.length; i++)
    scriptTags[i].src = 'other url';

var linkTags = div.getElementsByTagName('link');
for (var i = 0; i < linkTags.length; i++)
    linkTags[i].href = 'other url';
```

if you can use jQuery it's even easier

```
var div = $('<div/>').html(html);
div.find('<script/>').attr('src', 'other url');
div.find('<link/>').attr('href', 'other url');
```

Comment: thanks a lot. but i just do this while building my project not in production.